# How can I convert a mesh to a heightmap image using a scripting solution?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, image

I have got about 20000 DEM tiles in form of .glb meshes.

What I want to do is converting those meshes to 16bit grayscale height maps (of course using a scripting solution since 20000 files are too many for manual work).

If you know another tool that can do this easier, please also let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I would use a Material node set up to make higher parts of the mesh lighter (with the geometry node, not geometry nodes), and then render with an orthographic camera. To make things quicker, you might try importing the mesh as shape keys or a point cache somehow, and animating between them, then rendering as an image sequence.

Comment: You probably want a tool like [landserf](http://landserf.org/) that will read a dem and output a hgt file.  I suspect the tools that will do that automatically are expensive though.

Comment: Highly recommend [GDAL](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html).  Question may be more applicable on https://gis.stackexchange.com